# whmcs emails problem

Tags: php, whm

I am testing out the order process for a test webhost package I have already setup in whmcs. I have it set to automatically setup product upon first payment. When the order goes completes whmcs sends out only four emails to the new customer: "Order Confirmation", "Customer Invoice", "Invoice Payment Confirmation" and "Welcome". It does not send out a "New Account Information" email, which should contain the login details for cpanel. I can successfully log into the client area but not cPanel.

I checked the account from my administrator area and I see where it says active and paid also. I have tried several times to setup a test account to see if it would send the email with the cpanel login but it never sends it, though it sends all others.
Reply With Quote

Answer (score 1):

go to setup --- products/services --- edit the service and in the tab "details" select the "hosting account welcome email" in the "welcome email" field.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the tab "Utilities" tab in the WHMCS admin area, and then look through the log to see if any errors are happening when the system trys to connect to your cPanel/WHM server to create the account.

You could possibly see an error that goes along the lines of

"Module Create Failed - Service ID: 26 - Error: (Curl Error) Couldn't resolve host '' - code: 6"

Which indicates that WHMCS cannot connect to the host. You should then check to make sure that you have your hosting server properly configured in the "Servers" tab. Anyway to me it sounds like WHMCS cannot connect to the server to create the account and thus nothing happens.